# SetSound and SetVibrationPattern not working

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to play a custom mp3, placed in res/raw folder, on push notification but it always plays the default notification sound of my phone. I used xamarin and my testing phone is a Android 8.1. Even on earlier versions not always plays the custom sound. The following code is placed in the OnMessageReceived method. The notification from FCM has only the data tag and not the notification tag. Also the vibration pattern seems to be always the default one. Icon and Text works fine.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

                //Setting up Notification channels for android O and above
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {
                    SetupChannels(notificationManager, messageTitle);
                }

                var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                                             .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)

                                             .SetContentTitle(messageTitle)
                                             .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                             .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                             .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)

                                             .SetSound(global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + this.ApplicationContext.PackageName + "/raw/de900"))
                                             .SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 500, 1000, 500 })
                                             .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                             .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(messageBody));

                notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());

            }

            private void SetupChannels(NotificationManager notificationManager, string description)
            {
                // AudioAttributes.Builder.
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID, "EmersyChannel", NotificationImportance.Max)
                {                
                    LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public,   
                    Description = description
                };

                var audioattributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
                audioattributes.SetContentType(AudioContentType.Music);
                audioattributes.SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification);


                channel.SetSound(global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + this.ApplicationContext.PackageName + "/raw/de900"),
                    audioattributes.Build());
                channel.EnableVibration(true);
                channel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 200, 200, 30, 200, 30, 200, 200, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 200, 200, 30, 200, 30, 200, 200, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100 });
                channel.EnableLights(true);
                channel.LightColor = Color.Red;
                channel.SetShowBadge(true);            


                if (notificationManager != null)
                {
                    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

What's your phone ? I test your code on Google Pixel (Android 8.1),it works well. Then i test it on Xiaomi MI 5s Plus (Android 8.1),it doesn't work until i enter the phone's **Setting**,then set the **Sound** open in the notification channel of the application!
So it may be that some handset manufacturers have their own customization ,you could try to enter the phone's Setting to have a look!

**Update**:

the official link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough

Comment: I used a Samsung Galaxy J7 with Android 8.1 and in the Sound settings of the app appears Vibration on false and Sound the default sound. Why that?

Comment: This should be the problem of Samsung customization.If your Galaxy J7 has been updated to Android Oreo, this may be why your messaging application cannot use custom or non-default notification sounds. This is definitely not Android Oreo's fault. Other Android devices running this version of Android can still use non-default notification sounds.

Comment: Really!?!?!? Working with different android verisons is worse then working with different browsers ....

Comment: Now you can open the vibration option to see if you can get the notification of vibration with the default prompt sound ？

Comment: even vibrationpattern is only the default one

Comment: yes,as i say abov,it cannot use custom or non-default notification sounds.I think it's a unreasonable place of Samsung customization

Comment: maybe they will plan on bringing back this capability

Comment: i test it on Huawei device again,it also works well!

Comment: tested on a nexus 5x with andorid 8.1. no logo, default sound no vibration... damn. did you have a sample xamarin project so I can look what I do wrong?

Comment: I have given you the link to the official document,please see my update,in which there is Sample on github. I don't think there is anything wrong with your code

Comment: Any new discoveries?

Comment: no. because of missing time but what I see my code is quite similar